# Getting difficulty in using the AFNetworking(AFClient) for checking the network is available or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, afnetworking, ipad-2

I am using AfNetworking 1.0 into my app.
 I have create a singleton class of AFHTTPClient.
 following is my code;

```
 + (id)sharedInstance {

 static WebServices *__sharedInstance;
 static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
 dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
 NSString *WebServiceBaseURLString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"URL"];

 __sharedInstance = [[WebServices alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:WebServiceBaseURLString]];



 });


 return __sharedInstance;
 }



 - (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {


 self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];


 if (self) {

 NSString *accessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"UserToken"];
 NSLog(@"accessToken=%@",accessToken);

 [self setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:accessToken];

 NSLog(@"self=%@",self);

 [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

 self.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
 [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"]];



 }


 return self;
 }
```

its working file.

But now i want to use AFNetworkReachabilityStatus block

to check the network.

```
 [self setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status){
 NSLog(@"changed %d", status);

 }];
```

can any one advice me how to use AFNetworkReachabilityStatus block?

Comment: I'm using AFNetworking 2.0. Try in class A in viewDidLoad write this:[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
Then before you call your class do this:[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
    }]; and status it's enum

Comment: But i am using the AFNetworking version 1.0

Answer (score 0):

- (void)startMonitoringWithStatusChangeBlock:(void (^)(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status))block
  {

  [self stopMonitoring];

  if (!self.networkReachability) {
      return;
  }

  __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
  AFNetworkReachabilityStatusBlock callback = ^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
      __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;

  ```
  strongSelf.networkReachabilityStatus = status;
  if (block) {
      block(status);
  }
  ```

  };

  SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = {0, (__bridge void *)callback, AFNetworkReachabilityRetainCallback, AFNetworkReachabilityReleaseCallback, NULL};

  SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(self.networkReachability, AFNetworkReachabilityCallback, &context);

  SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;

  SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(self.networkReachability, &flags);

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status = AFNetworkReachabilityStatusForFlags(flags);
      callback(status);
  });

  SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(self.networkReachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

}